# populate array with nsmutabledata swift

Tags: ios, swift, byte, arrays

How can i populate an array with nsmutabledata in swift?

Heres my code :

```
    func hashTest(hash:[UInt8]) {
        var arrayOfBytes = NSMutableData()
        for var i = 0; i < hash.count; i++ {
            if i < 21 {
                arrayOfBytes.appendBytes(hash[i] as UInt8, length: 1)
            }
        }
    }
```

But i get the following error :

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(UInt8)'
```

Im trying to repeat something like this :

```
let endMarker = NSData(bytes: [0xa1, 0x11, 0xa9, 0xf5, 0xce, 0xdb, 0x18, 0xfb, 0xed, 0xd7, 0x67, 0x25, 0x86, 0xe7, 0xd6, 0x42, 0x96, 0x0f, 0x95, 0xe8] as [UInt8], length: 20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `&` in front of `hash[i]` ,  that will allow for the unsafe pointer to go into append bytes

```
func hashTest(var hash:[UInt8]) {
        var arrayOfBytes = NSMutableData()
        for var i = 0; i < hash.count; i++ {
        if i < 21 {
            arrayOfBytes.appendBytes(&hash[i], length: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting some warnings : ``` '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'UnsafePointer<Void>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<()>')```

Comment: I believe you need to add var to your parameter since you are passing it in.

Comment: @ViniciusAlbino note that those `for var` loops won't be available in Swift 3. You should get used to `for in` loops

Comment: @Leo Dabus Do you have documentation? Thought that was just a proposal last I knew

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Comment: the easiest for var substitute would be `for i in hash.indices {`

Comment: another point is you can and should declare arrayOfBytes using let.